# Write a dataframe to a csv file with multicharacter delimiter using Pandas/Python

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Any one can please help me to save a Pyspark Dataframe as csv file with multicharacter delimiter using Pandas /python.

Did a research and found to_csv of Pypspark/Pandas can take only 1 character delimiter and there is no option to provide multicharacter delimiter as separator.

dataframe.to_csv(file.csv, sep="@@")
Error: delimiter must be 1-character string

Link - https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Please let me know if any one has implemented this kind of scenario.

Comment: *"... save a Pyspark Dataframe as csv file with multicharacter delimiter using Pandas /python."* -- why do you want to use pandas for the export when you can export the pyspark df directly?

Comment: @samkart, because in older version of Pyspark i.e. version 3 below - we can't export with multicharacter delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the pandas to_csv function only allows single-character delimiters/separators.

So, Use [numpy-savetxt](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#numpy-savetxt).

```
np.savetxt(file.dat, chunk_data.values, delimiter='~|', fmt='%s',encoding='utf-8')
```

Then you can convert it to `csv` format.

Comment: is there any other way than the numpy??? Since data is huge and we wanted to use the distributed capability of spark here .Entire code is developed using Pyspark, so thinking about a solution around Pyspark if there is .Can you please let me know if numpy also gives the same performance as compare to spark.

Comment: About the performance, there are some references that say Spark is faster than Numpy when it comes to big data handling. But for this special problem, AFAIK, we don't have any other one-line option.

Answer (score 0):

In pyspark, you can use `option("delimiter", "@@")` for multi-character delimiter:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([('Ash', 25), ('Bob', 30), ('Cat', 20)], ['name', 'age'])

[Out]:
+----+---+
|name|age|
+----+---+
| Ash| 25|
| Bob| 30|
| Cat| 20|
+----+---+

df.repartition(1).write.mode("overwrite").option("header",True).option("delimiter", "@@").csv("/content/sample_data/test.csv")

[Out]:
name@@age
Ash@@25
Bob@@30
Cat@@20
```

Comment: this work in higher version of spark i.e .version 3 and above.....we have lower version on spark in our cluster  - spark 2.4